# Imagus alternative for Firefox 57

Tags: web-browser, firefox

Is there an Imagus addon alternative for Firefox 57?
It's been recently disabled in Nightly.

Edit:

Imagus load image or image link without the need to click it, it works for certain videos too by playing it with just hover

Comment: Yeah,  I know, that's why I didn't add much of info actually, I'll try to improve it though...

Comment: PS: For the question "Alternative to X with FF57+" I've [created a Gist](https://gist.github.com/IzzySoft/db7c7d4243283ca84b3abd8b94114e2e). Whoever can fill some gaps is welcome to comment :)

Comment: I still use Firefox cause it's the only browser I can use without entirely filling my RAM with 20+ tabs open.

Comment: And v57 manage the well the RAM for that purpose, everything else out there has +/- chrome behind it. So let's just wait and see. I think by the time 57 will be stable, we'll have our favorites addon supported or at least get an alternative.